# Reading in a data file (txt) into java variables

Tags: java, io

I have a data file "inventory.dat" with these contents:

```
Item ID             |Item Name                               |Item Description                                                                                    |Weight       |Quantity      |Price       |Isle                |Bin
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BK1012923           |#8 x 1" Wood Screws (Qty 8)             |#8 x 1" Wood Screws (Qty 8) - Plastic bag                                                           |0.04         |144           |0.65        |Isle-N23            |Bin-N23-14-3
BK1022344           |#8 x 1" Wood Screws (Qty 8)             |#8 x 1 1/2" Wood Screws (Qty 8) - Plastic bag                                                       |0.06         |144           |0.65        |Isle-N23            |Bin-N23-14-3
BK1022344           |#8 x 1" Wood Screws (Qty 8)             |#8 x 1 1/2" Wood Screws (Qty 8) - Plastic bag                                                       |0.06         |50            |0.65        |Isle-S18            |Bin-S18-01-2

Summary: 338 items   Total Value: $219.70
```

I want to be able to read in each piece of data into separate variables for Item ID, Item Name, Item Description, Weight, Quantity, Price, Isle, and Bin. How would I go about doing this using `BufferedReader`?

Summary and Total Value should be ignored.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * 
 *
 */
public class FileRead {
    public static void main (String[] argv) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        String line;
        String data;
        ArrayList<String> itemID = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> itemName = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> itemDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> weight = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> quant = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Float> price = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<String> aisle = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> bin = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/inventory.dat"));

            while ((line = reader.readLine() != null)) {
                //
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You would go about it by reading the file and parsing the data to get what you want from it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post the code where you attempt to read in the file and we can help with specific questions.

Comment: just posted right now. just not sure what to do in while loop

Comment: To help you start, `line.split("|")` will split the line at every | and give you an array of `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. I have used `line.split("\\|")` to split the line with `|` as delimiter. And since there is an empty line in the file before Summary and Total you can break the loop there by using    `if(line.isEmpty())`

```
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/inventory.dat"));
        //ignore first two lines
        line = reader.readLine(); //read first line
        line = reader.readLine(); //read second line

        line = reader.readLine(); //read third line
        while (line != null){

            if(line.isEmpty())
                break;

            String [] l  = line.split("\\|"); //Split the lines

            //Add data
            itemID.add(l[0]);
            itemName.add(l[1]);
            itemDesc.add(l[2]);
            weight.add(l[3]);
            quant.add(Integer.parseInt(l[4].trim()));
            price.add(Float.parseFloat(l[5].trim()));
            aisle.add(l[6]);
            bin.add(l[7]);

            line = reader.readLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: for `quant.add(Integer.parseInt(l[4].trim()));` it runs into a number format exception, since it reads in "144           " with a bunch of empty spaces after the int

Comment: @vnguyen56 `.trim()` removes those spaces. It worked fine for me. You should check what is `l[4]` to see the problem.